# How to archive large tables to CSV in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, csv

In SQL Server 2014, I want to locally archive some large tables to CSV. The tables have millions of records. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BCP out as below:

```
bcp.exe yourtable out "D:\yourtableoutputdata.csv" -T -c -C 65001 -t
```

Comment: we can only have 1,048,576 rows in excel. How can I create split CSVs in small manageable sizes.

Comment: Use the -F and --L parameters to specify first and last rows for a given command. Trying to load millions of routes into Excel is going to be challenging for you though.

Answer (score 0):

You can done using this command. Open `Command Prompt Run As Administrator` and copy paste below command. It will export to CSV

```
sqlcmd -S . -d DatabaseName -E -s',' -W -Q "SELECT * FROM TableName" > C:\Test.csv
```